# Any way to generate a function with arguments dependant on compile-time info via macros?

Tags: c, function, macros, ansi-c

I was thinking about creating a high-performance library for online judge type tasks. Among others I wanna include high-performance IO facilities and some algorithmic data structures like segment tree, etc.

The trouble I'm facing is the functionality/performance tradeoff. My idea to solve this tradeoff is to create macros that will serve as templates of procedures, and then enable the user to switch functionality on or off via flags.

To ilustrate: If the user writes:

```
DECLARE_READ(long long, NEOF|NSGN, readll)
```

They will get a function called `readll` that reads a `long long int` and for extra performance assumes that the read integer is not negative and actually present in the input before EOF condition.

One problem that arises with such an architecture is that sometimes the number of parameters of functions will have to depend on specified features. For example, the ctor of the segment tree will have to take extra arguments if the need for lazy evaluation in specified.

Is the any way to build a macro that would create a function with or without a specific parameter basing on compile-time info passed to this macro in any way?

I mean sth like this: (pseudocode, I know this particular way does not and can not work):

```
#define DECLARE_SEGMENT_TREE(FNAME, FEATURES) \
    __inline__ void FNAME##_create( \
            size_t number_of_elemens, \
            size_t element_size \
            #if (FEATURES&LAZY)!=0 \
                    , void* reserved_value_meaning_not_yet_computed \
            #endif \
    ) { \
            /* ctor logic here */ \
    }
```

Comment: possible alternative: use a `struct` (possibly containing `union`s) as the single parameter.

Comment: The reason I'm thinkin about such a bizzarre architecture is that the alternatives seem even worse... Require features flags passed each time a function is called? Risks loosing the coherence of a container if the container is accessed with different feature flags than it was created with. Create a static set of function variations with features encoded in their names? But the number of such functions would grow quadratically.

Comment: you could also consider combining it with an "*interface `struct`*" containing only function pointers and some *factory function* returning an instance of the interface for the specified set of features ... (just another idea, I'm not a big fan of preprocessor tricks once they get too fancy)

Answer (score 0):

On gcc, and other compiler you can do:

```
#define THIRD(a,b,c,...) c
#define DECLARE_SEGMENT_TREE(FNAME, ...) THIRD(FNAME,##__VA_ARGS__,"this if are two arguments","else this if one argument")
```

but with Microsoft compiler this not working; this is my universal solution (work on gcc, cl and older tcc):

```
// MSVC check if __VA_ARGS__ isn't NULL (call with CHECK_NULL(,##__VA_ARGS__) )
#define CHECK_NULL(a,...) ,##__VA_ARGS__
#define THIRD(a,b,c,...) c
// MSVC read the right number of arguments (call with double parentheses ex: _IF((CHECK_NULL,this _ELSE that)) )
#define _IF(args) THIRD args
#define _ELSE ,

#define DECLARE_SEGMENT_TREE(FNAME, ...) \
    _IF((CHECK_NULL(,##__VA_ARGS__), { \
        "this if are two arguments" \
    } \
    _ELSE "else this if one argument"))
```

This check if arguments is one or two; I have helped you? :)

Answer (score 0):

> Any way to generate a function with arguments dependant on compile-time info via macros?

Absolutely!  But it requires a fair amount of preprocessor metaprogramming.  Methinks you might be facing yet another tradeoff.

Nevertheless, here it is; this is one approach showing you what it takes to pull this off.

## Caveat

One thing that we cannot do is use *macros* to evaluate *expressions*; and by *expression* I'm referring to grammatical entities defined by the language using the typical symbolic operators.

For example, given `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are defined as integer literals (with reasonable range), we *can* with some difficulty come up with a macro set such that `SUM(X,Y,Z)` expands to the sum; but it's *impossible* to come up with a macro set such that `COMPUTE(X+Y+Z)` expands to the sum.

In particular, you showed an example usage:

```
/* Won't work: */ DECLARE_READ(long long, /* --> */ NEOF|NSGN, readll)
```

No matter how we define `DECLARE_READ`, there's not much useful to be done with `NEOF|NSGN`.  A more natural version of a feature set for CPP programming would simply be a tuple of tokens; that would look more like this:

```
DECLARE_READ(long long, (NEOF,NSGN), readll)
```

...now *that* we can code to!

## Interface macros

Before getting into the *implementation* of this approach, I'll start with the "interface"; that is, the macros you'll actually be dealing with.  First, there are some high level formal concepts to nail down.

Let's say that a **feature** is a particular token you'll use in a feature set.  For each feature, you need to define a *matching pattern macro* for the framework:

```
#define NEOF_test_NEOF ,Y
#define NSGN_test_NSGN ,Y
#define LAZY_test_LAZY ,Y
```

These pattern macros are used by a core pattern matcher to in effect implement an *equality comparison* operator for features.  This serves an analogous need to the use of bitwise operations, where you would need to allocate unique bits within an integer to each feature (`#define NEOF 1`, `#define NSGN 2`, `#define LAZY 4`, and so on).

Given a set of features, a **feature set** is a tuple of features; that is, a feature set is defined by a comma delimited set of features surrounded by parentheses, as mentioned at the top of the post, like this:  `(NEOF,NSGN)`.

This in mind, the framework supports a macro:

```
HAS_FEATURE(Q_,FSET_)
```

...where `Q_` is a *feature*, and `FSET_` is a *feature set*, this macro expands to `Y` if the specified *feature* is in the *feature set*; otherwise it expands to `N`.  For example, given the above features:

```
HAS_FEATURE(LAZY,(NEOF,NSGN)) // expands to N
HAS_FEATURE(NSGN,(NEOF,NSGN)) // expands to Y
```

This macro:

```
EXPAND_IF(PREDICATE_,TO_)
```

...accepts `Y` or `N` as the first argument.  The *second* argument is a series of tokens *within parentheses*.  If called with `Y` as the first argument, this will expand to the specified set of tokens *with the parentheses removed*.  If called with `N` as the first argument, this expands to nothing.

This is enough interface to *literally* implement your sample macro:

```
#include "the-framework-below.h"
#define NEOF_test_NEOF ,Y
#define NSGN_test_NSGN ,Y
#define LAZY_test_LAZY ,Y
#define DECLARE_SEGMENT_TREE(FNAME, FEATURES) \
    __inline__ void FNAME##_create( \
        size_t number_of_elemens, \
        size_t element_size \
        EXPAND_IF(HAS_FEATURE(LAZY,FEATURES) /* #if (FEATURES&LAZY)!=0 */ \
                (, void* rvmnyc) \
        ) /* #endif */ \
    ) { \
        /* ctor logic here */ \
    }
DECLARE_SEGMENT_TREE(foo, (NSGN,NEOF)) // expands to:
// __inline__ void foo_create( size_t number_of_elemens, size_t element_size ) { }
DECLARE_SEGMENT_TREE(bar, (NSGN,LAZY)) // expands to:
// __inline__ void foo_create( size_t number_of_elemens, size_t element_size , void* rvmnyc) { }
```

...however, I don't quite think this is "enough"; your pseudocode macro suggests *evaluating an expression* containing bitwise arithmetic.  And whereas *technically* all you did here was test for membership of a feature, if you had support for such expressions, you would be able to do other things such as an analogous `#if (!(FEATURES&LAZY)&&!(FEATURES&NSGN))`.

For this reason, I've made some logical operation macros:

```
LOGICAL_NOT(C_)
LOGICAL_OR(...)
LOGICAL_AND(...)
```

All of these accept only `Y` and `N` as arguments; the `LOGICAL_OR` and `LOGICAL_AND` operators can be used with multiple arguments (up to 9 but can be expanded).

With this you can do more complicated things, like this:

```
#define NFIL_test_NFIL ,Y

#define DECLARE_OPERATE(FNAME, FEATURES) \
   static void FNAME##_operate(void* base \
             EXPAND_IF(HAS_FEATURE(LAZY,FEATURES), \
                     (, char* buffer)) \
   ) { \
       EXPAND_IF(LOGICAL_NOT(HAS_FEATURE(LAZY,FEATURES)), \
                 (char* buffer = malloc(999);) \
       ) \
       EXPAND_IF(LOGICAL_AND(LOGICAL_NOT(HAS_FEATURE(LAZY,FEATURES)), \
                             LOGICAL_NOT(HAS_FEATURE(NFIL,FEATURES))), \
                 (memset(buffer, 0, 999);) \
       ) \
       operate(buffer); \
       EXPAND_IF(LOGICAL_NOT(HAS_FEATURE(LAZY,FEATURES)), \
                 (free(buffer);) \
       ) \
   }
DECLARE_OPERATE(alloc_skipfill,(NFIL,NEOF)) // expands to:
// static void alloc_skipfill_operate(void* base) {
//    char* buffer = malloc(999); operate(buffer); free(buffer);
// }
```

## Demo

[Via godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/TkAh8c)

## The framework

```
#define LOGICAL_NOT(C_) SELECT(GLUE(LOGICAL_NOT_UTILITY_,C_),bad_boolean_value(C_))
#define LOGICAL_OR(...) GLUE(LOGICAL_OR_,COUNT(__VA_ARGS__))((__VA_ARGS__))
#define LOGICAL_AND(...) GLUE(LOGICAL_AND_,COUNT(__VA_ARGS__))((__VA_ARGS__))
#define EXPAND_IF(C_,TO_) EVAL(EXPAND_IF_FOR SELECT(GLUE(EXPAND_IF_UTILITY_,C_),TO_))
#define HAS_FEATURE(Q_,FSET_) GLUE(HAS_FEATURE_,COUNT FSET_)(Q_,FSET_)

#define GLUE(A,B) GLUE_INDIRECT(A,B)
#   define GLUE_INDIRECT(A,B) A##B
#define EVAL(...) __VA_ARGS__
#ifndef _MSC_VER
# define COUNT(...)  COUNT_INDIRECT(__VA_ARGS__, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1,)
# define FIRST(...)  FIRST_INDIRECT(__VA_ARGS__,)
# define SECOND(...) SECOND_INDIRECT(__VA_ARGS__,,)
# define TAIL(...)   TAIL_INDIRECT(__VA_ARGS__)
# define SELECT(...) SELECT_INDIRECT(__VA_ARGS__,)
#else
# define COUNT(...)  EVAL(COUNT_INDIRECT(__VA_ARGS__, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1,))
# define FIRST(...)  EVAL(FIRST_INDIRECT(__VA_ARGS__,))
# define SECOND(...) EVAL(SECOND_INDIRECT(__VA_ARGS__,,))
# define TAIL(...)   EVAL(TAIL_INDIRECT(__VA_ARGS__))
# define SELECT(...) EVAL(SELECT_INDIRECT(__VA_ARGS__,))
#endif
#   define COUNT_INDIRECT(_,_9,_8,_7,_6,_5,_4,_3,_2,X,...) X
#   define FIRST_INDIRECT(X,...) X
#   define SECOND_INDIRECT(_,X,...) X
#   define TAIL_INDIRECT(X,...) (__VA_ARGS__)
#   define SELECT_INDIRECT(PATTERN_,DEFAULT_,...) SECOND(PATTERN_, DEFAULT_)

#   define HAS_FEATURE_1(Q_,FSET_) SELECT(GLUE(Q_,GLUE(_test_,FIRST FSET_)),N)
#   define HAS_FEATURE_2(Q_,FSET_) SELECT(GLUE(Q_,GLUE(_test_,FIRST FSET_)),HAS_FEATURE_1(Q_,TAIL FSET_))
#   define HAS_FEATURE_3(Q_,FSET_) SELECT(GLUE(Q_,GLUE(_test_,FIRST FSET_)),HAS_FEATURE_2(Q_,TAIL FSET_))
#   define HAS_FEATURE_4(Q_,FSET_) SELECT(GLUE(Q_,GLUE(_test_,FIRST FSET_)),HAS_FEATURE_3(Q_,TAIL FSET_))
#   define HAS_FEATURE_5(Q_,FSET_) SELECT(GLUE(Q_,GLUE(_test_,FIRST FSET_)),HAS_FEATURE_4(Q_,TAIL FSET_))
#   define HAS_FEATURE_6(Q_,FSET_) SELECT(GLUE(Q_,GLUE(_test_,FIRST FSET_)),HAS_FEATURE_5(Q_,TAIL FSET_))
#   define HAS_FEATURE_7(Q_,FSET_) SELECT(GLUE(Q_,GLUE(_test_,FIRST FSET_)),HAS_FEATURE_6(Q_,TAIL FSET_))
#   define HAS_FEATURE_8(Q_,FSET_) SELECT(GLUE(Q_,GLUE(_test_,FIRST FSET_)),HAS_FEATURE_7(Q_,TAIL FSET_))
#   define HAS_FEATURE_9(Q_,FSET_) SELECT(GLUE(Q_,GLUE(_test_,FIRST FSET_)),HAS_FEATURE_8(Q_,TAIL FSET_))

#   define LOGICAL_NOT_UTILITY_Y ,N
#   define LOGICAL_NOT_UTILITY_N ,Y

#   define LOGICAL_CHECK_Y ,Y
#   define LOGICAL_CHECK_N ,N

#   define LOGICAL_OR_SHORTCIRCUIT_UTILITY_Y ,Y
#   define LOGICAL_OR_1(C_) SELECT(GLUE(LOGICAL_CHECK_,FIRST C_),bad_boolean_value(C_))
#   define LOGICAL_OR_2(C_) SELECT(GLUE(LOGICAL_OR_SHORTCIRCUIT_UTILITY_,FIRST C_),LOGICAL_OR_1(TAIL C_))
#   define LOGICAL_OR_3(C_) SELECT(GLUE(LOGICAL_OR_SHORTCIRCUIT_UTILITY_,FIRST C_),LOGICAL_OR_2(TAIL C_))
#   define LOGICAL_OR_4(C_) SELECT(GLUE(LOGICAL_OR_SHORTCIRCUIT_UTILITY_,FIRST C_),LOGICAL_OR_3(TAIL C_))
#   define LOGICAL_OR_5(C_) SELECT(GLUE(LOGICAL_OR_SHORTCIRCUIT_UTILITY_,FIRST C_),LOGICAL_OR_4(TAIL C_))
#   define LOGICAL_OR_6(C_) SELECT(GLUE(LOGICAL_OR_SHORTCIRCUIT_UTILITY_,FIRST C_),LOGICAL_OR_5(TAIL C_))
#   define LOGICAL_OR_7(C_) SELECT(GLUE(LOGICAL_OR_SHORTCIRCUIT_UTILITY_,FIRST C_),LOGICAL_OR_6(TAIL C_))
#   define LOGICAL_OR_8(C_) SELECT(GLUE(LOGICAL_OR_SHORTCIRCUIT_UTILITY_,FIRST C_),LOGICAL_OR_7(TAIL C_))
#   define LOGICAL_OR_9(C_) SELECT(GLUE(LOGICAL_OR_SHORTCIRCUIT_UTILITY_,FIRST C_),LOGICAL_OR_8(TAIL C_))

#   define LOGICAL_AND_SHORTCIRCUIT_UTILITY_N ,N
#   define LOGICAL_AND_1(C_) SELECT(GLUE(LOGICAL_CHECK_,FIRST C_),bad_boolean_value(C_))
#   define LOGICAL_AND_2(C_) SELECT(GLUE(LOGICAL_AND_SHORTCIRCUIT_UTILITY_,FIRST C_),LOGICAL_AND_1(TAIL C_))
#   define LOGICAL_AND_3(C_) SELECT(GLUE(LOGICAL_AND_SHORTCIRCUIT_UTILITY_,FIRST C_),LOGICAL_AND_2(TAIL C_))
#   define LOGICAL_AND_4(C_) SELECT(GLUE(LOGICAL_AND_SHORTCIRCUIT_UTILITY_,FIRST C_),LOGICAL_AND_3(TAIL C_))
#   define LOGICAL_AND_5(C_) SELECT(GLUE(LOGICAL_AND_SHORTCIRCUIT_UTILITY_,FIRST C_),LOGICAL_AND_4(TAIL C_))
#   define LOGICAL_AND_6(C_) SELECT(GLUE(LOGICAL_AND_SHORTCIRCUIT_UTILITY_,FIRST C_),LOGICAL_AND_5(TAIL C_))
#   define LOGICAL_AND_7(C_) SELECT(GLUE(LOGICAL_AND_SHORTCIRCUIT_UTILITY_,FIRST C_),LOGICAL_AND_6(TAIL C_))
#   define LOGICAL_AND_8(C_) SELECT(GLUE(LOGICAL_AND_SHORTCIRCUIT_UTILITY_,FIRST C_),LOGICAL_AND_7(TAIL C_))
#   define LOGICAL_AND_9(C_) SELECT(GLUE(LOGICAL_AND_SHORTCIRCUIT_UTILITY_,FIRST C_),LOGICAL_AND_8(TAIL C_))

#   define EXPAND_IF_UTILITY_N ,()
#   define EXPAND_IF_FOR(...) __VA_ARGS__
```

### VERY BRIEF description

A lot of these macros use standard techniques.  Two techniques at the heart of this implementation are:

- The `COUNT` macro (very common idiom; though confusing at first, it's basically an argument shifter akin to something like a "register shifter")
- A pattern matcher macro (also common, maybe somewhat less so)

This `COUNT` macro is used to jump into patterned sets of macros, designed to be easily expanded.  This is one strategy for handling indeterminate sized tuples.

*Pattern matching* in the C preprocessor essentially involves building a "pattern token" as the first argument of a macro that nominally ignores the first argument; for example, the `SECOND` macro.  In this case, `SECOND` will as its name implies return the *second* argument.  When this occurs, you can call the pattern token an *unmatched pattern*, and that second argument becomes the *default expansion*.

If the pattern token itself is an object-like macro, and that macro expands to `, REPLACEMENT`, then the *pattern token* will expand during the *argument substitution* phase of preprocessing.  The net result is that `REPLACEMENT` becomes the *new* second argument.  In this case, the object-like macro itself can be thought of as a *matching token macro*; and its `REPLACEMENT` as the *matching replacement*.

The implementation above uses pattern matching to implement the logical operators and, along with the feature definition requirement, to create an equality comparison operation.